# Constraining a parameter in a 4 level variable In a propensity score regression

Tags: logistic, sas, propensity-scores, parameterization, constraint

I’m generating a propensity score using logistic regression in SAS. The model predicts compliance with a quality measure. I will match patients into groups who actually complied and not complied with the measure with equal predicted probability to comply versus not comply with the measure.

One of the predictor variables has 4 levels. Three of them are predictors of complying with the measure, but by rules of the quality measure, the 4th level defines non-compliance and should not be used to predict compliance and kept out of the score.

Can I include the 4 level variable but restrict the parameter of the 4th level to zero or neutral in generating the score so that it plays no role in predicting compliance but the other 3 levels do?

---

*(copied from answer)*

Thank you for helping me think about this. Treatment here is full compliance with all the components (7 of them) of a quality measure. Treatment in this context starts precisely when all components are passed = compliance, or when any one required item is failed = non-compliance. It’s an all or nothing measure so you cannot be “treated” or compliant until all elements are passed.The level that defines non-compliance is when a certain lab is not checked. It’s part of the definition of compliance, the measure literally requires the lab is checked or you fail. So that level “not collected” fully defines “not treated.” That’s why I’ve thought to leave it out.

Other levels of that variable are ranges of the result. Those ranges suggest severity of illness and therefore predict compliance. In of themselves those other levels do not define complete compliance with the measure because there are 6 other components, and those other levels cannot lead to failure.

I’ve considered your solution. The problem with excluding those patients in deriving the propensity score is that we are trying to determine the effect of compliance on mortality. Some patients in the dataset will fail by not having the lab, lactate, assessed. If I want to know the full effect of compliance on mortality I need to leave them in.

I considered just leaving this lab out of my model, but it strongly predicts compliance and 3 levels are available before treatment is assigned. Hence, I wondered about controlling the parameter estimate of the “not collected” level to be neutral in the regression that determines the propensity score — leaves the patients in but gives them no weight in terms of predicting compliance.

Comment: Can you say something more about the 4th level of your predictor and why it predicts non-compliance 100% accurately all of the time?  My concern is that the 4th level is actually not a true covariate, but might be a measure obtained only AFTER treatment has been assigned, in which case, it would not be an appropriate variable to include in your propensity score model.  Or is it that your sample is just unlucky and by happenstance, every subject coded at the 4th level also happened to be non-compliant?

Comment: It seems it might be appropriate to completely remove all those coded at the 4th level from your analysis all together and restrict your findings to only those coded levels 1, 2, or 3. Can you provide a real-life interpretation and description of the variable and the levels?

I would also recommend removing "SAS" from the title, as this question has nothing to do with SAS, but with propensity scores, regardless of what software package you use to analyze the data.

Comment: Please register & merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply replace all instances where subjects classified into the 4th level of your predictor as missing ("." in SAS by default), and then perform the regression, SAS will automatically delete those subjects from your analysis.  Your analysis will then be restricted to only those subjects who were classified into levels 1, 2, or 3.  This seems to be the most straightforward approach from a programming perspective.

Equivalently (depending on your parameterization settings in SAS) and perhaps more intuitively, you could also create two binary variables, say $Level_1$ and $Level_2$ coded 0/1 for each of the 3 levels that could potentially explain compliance/non-compliance (I'm assuming here that compliance is akin to treatment and non-compliance is akin to control).  In this case, those in level 1, would be be coded:

$\text{Level 1}=\begin{cases}
Level_{1}=1\\
Level_{2}=0
\end{cases}$

those in level 2 would be coded:

$\text{Level 2}=\begin{cases}
Level_{1}=0\\
Level_{2}=1
\end{cases}$

and those in level 3 would be coded:

$\text{Level 3}=\begin{cases}
Level_{1}=0\\
Level_{2}=0
\end{cases}$.

Those in level 4 would be excluded from your analysis and should be dropped from your analysis and findings applied only to those in levels 1, 2, and 3.

Note, however some of the concerns I raised in my comments to your question.